# read messages from kafka in east and west

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a scenario where we need to read msgs from kafka-EAST and kafka-WEST, to where the producer is sending messages alternatively.

Kafka-EAST has a topic T1 and the replication topic **T1.R from 'WEST'**. The same way, Kafka-WEST has a same topic T1 and the replication topic **T1.R from 'EAST'**. In effect, at any given region we will have full set of messages produced by producer. All is well, till now.

Now, we need to read the messages.

From EAST, if I start reading the messages in batches of 40K msgs and if kafka-EAST goes down at given point of time during reading the batch, I can start reading from WEST (of course, the same reading failure applies to WEST also).

However, **the offset from kafka-EAST is different from kafka-WEST.** This is the origin of the problem to read by ascertaining the position from where to start reading in other region!!! So, I will go clue less where to start reading from, in WEST region.

Well, I am thinking of offset metadata and taking the time stamp as a reference and go little bit back of that time stamp and start reading from WEST. But, if the EAST kafka exists, then only it is possible to read the latest offset and it's time stamp (however, if it exists, then there is no problem, i can continue to read there itself!!!) If it is dead, we cant read that also, because offset is stored within kafka. Of course, when it comes back, we can read and that is not what I am trying to solve.

When EAST kafka is down, i want to start reading from WEST. I can externalize the offset and commit only after each batch reading is successful. When we get a signal that EAST kafka is down, WEST read gets activated to start reading from the same batch id as that of EAST's last commit.

Is this the best approach? or do we have any standard patterns to solve this problem? Please note, we have already consider cross zones. We are solutioning at region level only now.

Comment: I think your concern that Kafka being down is valid, but I think if you increase the replication factor enough over enough brokers with a reasonable min ISR setting within that topic, the event that your topics will be unavailable will really only occur if a network switch or datacenter rack or availability zone goes down. In other words, you should focus on making highly available, single aggregated Kafka clusters (via MirrorMaker, for example), rather than dealing with offset management joining two disparate clusters and routing requests when one or the other is available

Comment: so i'm curious to know kafka-EAST in one cluster and kafka-WEST is another cluster? sorry i'm trying to understand @user

Comment: i agree with you @cricket_007, i'm trying to understand can we have design like this topic on one cluster having replication factor on different cluster? is that possible ?

Comment: @Deadpool The replica placement is not across clusters. You would need to configure matching topics beforehand in the clusters and use MirrorMaker to copy topic data. Confluent Replicator is able to copy the configurations itself, but it's obviously not a free solution. I've been using some MirrorMaker message handler that will periodically poll and sync topic configurations, but it's proprietary, so can't share it

Comment: okay got it thank you @cricket_007

Comment: Kafka-EAST and Kafka-WEST are two different clusters and the same named topics are replicated across EAST and WEST.

Comment: Just another thought, while we have two clusters across east and west, can we have a program(in my case it is scala) that reads two different dStreams from east and west, combine both dStreams into one, dedup and use that OR feed both dStreams into one collection and read from there in both east and west. At any given point of time, use either east or west. If one fails the other one need to be used. However, the offset commit issue pops up in this case. So, we will not rely on kafka offset, we will maintain an external store for collection read position, reachable to both regions. How is it?

Comment: By the way, I dont have any control on the Kafka setting. I am supposed to device a solution, given the set up. So, it is only about solving the issue reading from given kafka setup

Comment: There are many companies using Kafka as log where entire application depends on kafka’s high availability. You should not do what you mentioned in question because it has more work for your producer(s) as well. Using external offset store meaning making it highly available too. And other minor things like back off and retry if offset is not yet present in other Kafka cluster.